# Confusion over a limit. Different ways of solving give different answers?

Tags: calculus, limits

**Qn:** If it is given that
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{x^2 - x - 2}{x + 1} - ax - b = 1
$$
then a and b must be?

Now, I tried doing this by 2 methods.

**Method 1:**
$$ \frac{x^2 - x - 2}{x + 1} - ax - b $$
$$ = (x - 2) - ax - b $$

Since the limit is finite, $a$ must be $= 1$ and so, $b = -3$

**Method 2:**
$$ \frac{x^2 - x - 2}{x + 1} - ax - b $$
$$ = \frac{x^2(1 - \frac 1 x - \frac2 {x^2})}{x(1 + \frac1x)} - ax - b $$
$$ = \frac{x - 1 - \frac2x}{(1 + \frac1x)} - ax - b $$

as $x \to \infty$, we have the above expression
$$ = x - ax - b$$

So, $a = 1$ and $b = -1$

Which of the above is correct?

Comment: If so, can you please present any more solutions to this, of the infinite possible solutions?

Comment: You have a single equation in two unknowns, so naturally you should expect infinitely many solutions. In fact, as long as $a=1$, it works: put everything over the denominator $x+1$ and you see that $b$ only affects the linear and constant terms upstairs. These don't affect the limit at infinity.

Comment: Is the limit applied to the entire LHS or just to the fraction?If you can clarify this then may be I think I got the answer for your question.

Comment: The limit is applied to the entire LHS

Comment: @Lubin, I don't quite get you: "put everything over the denominator x+1 and you see that b only affects the linear and constant terms upstairs". I do understand that b affects only the constant term. How does it affect the linear term? And secondly, what do you mean by "put everything over the denominator"?

Comment: The first method is correct. On the second one, I don't think you that the reasoning why that fractions go away are correct since you have them multiplied by x in front. Something is fishy there but I cant state exact definitions to proove it.

Comment: @Belov, we've actually been solving limit problems in which the variable tends to infinity by the 2nd method most of the times. That's how I actually did it when the question was presented to me. But then someone pointed out the 1st method and contradicted me. So we got confused and hence the question is over here!

Comment: @Belov, think of it this way. When $x$ becomes very, very, very large, then the numerator will, in all its glory, be just $x^2$. The denominator will be simply $x$ at that time. So, overall the ratio would simply be $x$. You get the point? (Btw, this is just the qualitative way of presenting the 2nd method!)

Comment: Yes, but you are taking the limit at infinity when x becomes very very large, but then the limit is not x, but is infinity. Can you see my point?

Comment: The only way to resolve fraction limits is 1) Get rid of them, which is method 1). 2) Make everything a fraction then either resolve the limits to constants or devide by the highest power of x, or use Lopithals rule. I dont think you can take the limit of the fraction, and in sucha weird way, and leave the x,ax and b untouched.

Comment: @Isp, but the link I gave in your answer says the opposite

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8430/discussion-between-parth-thakkar-and-belov)

Comment: just for fun ... i hope you won't be offended 
$$\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\to\infty}x + 1 &=  \lim_{x\to\infty} x \left( 1 + \frac 1 x  \right )\\ 
 &= \lim_{x\to\infty} x \cdot  \lim_{x\to\infty } \left(1 + \frac 1 x  \right )\\ 
 &=  \lim_{x\to\infty} x \cdot 1\\ 
 &=  \lim_{x\to\infty} x \\ 
\end{align*}$$
$$\lim_{x\to\infty} x + 1 - \lim_{x\to\infty} x = 0 \implies 1 = 0 \; \; \text{ Q.E.D.}$$
A new way to prove!! $0 = 1$

Comment: @experimentX: infinity-infinity is not equal to zero

Comment: @Adam, his sole aim is to display that what I have done is wrong, and hence he shows that using what I've done, we arrive at a contradiction. He is just showing that what I've done is wrong!

Comment: @experimentX, of course I won't be offended!! Come on! Btw, this was a nice thing...nice example to remember :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In method 2 you are losing too much information. In particular, you lose the linear and constant term in the numerator of the fraction.

To be more particular,
you need to write
$\frac{x^2 - x - 2}{x + 1} - ax - b
=\frac{x^2 - x - 2 - (x+1)(ax+b)}{x + 1}
=\frac{x^2 - x - 2 - (ax^2+x(a+b)+b)}{x + 1}
=\frac{x^2(1-a) - x(1+a+b) - 2 -b}{x + 1}
$.

If you want the limit of this to exist,
you must have $a = 1$, or else the $x^2$ term
will cause the fraction to be unbounded.
The fraction then becomes
$\frac{- x(2+b) - 2 -b}{x + 1}
$.

Any value of $b$ allows the limit to exist,
since it is of the form
$\frac{linear}{linear}$.
To have the limit be $1$,
we will ignore the fortuitous factorization
that can be done with the numerator
and just look at the coefficients of $x$.

For the limit to be $1$,
the coefficients of $x$ is the numerator and denominator must be equal,
so that $1 = -(2+b)$,
or $b = -3$.

Note that the constant terms in this fraction do not matter.
In other words,
if $c$ and $d$ are any real numbers,
to make $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{- x(2+b)+c}{x + d} = 1$,
you must choose $b = -3$.
The limit then becomes
$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{x+c}{x + d}$,
and this limit is $1$ for any $c$ and $d$.

To see this,
note that
$\frac{x+c}{x + d}-1
= \frac{x+c-(x+d)}{x + d}
= \frac{c-d}{x + d}
$
and this goes to $0$
as $x \to \infty$.

Comment: "For the limit to be 1, the coefficients of x is the numerator and denominator must be equal...". Aren't you doing the same thing that I did in the 2nd method - what you call losing too much of information, in particular, the constant term?

Comment: No. In your second method, you had $x^2(1+something/x+something/x^2)$ and, letting $x \to \infty$, said this became like $x^2$. The problem is that, to make the quotient be like $ax+b$, you need the term that you allowed to vanish. In my case, note that I did $not$ divide by $x$ - I subtracted terms, never losing information. Only when I finally got an expression of the form $constant/linear$ did I say that it went to zero.

Comment: I had actually realised my mistake (and only that's why I accepted your answer), but couldn't get time to comment. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

**Method $1$ is correct**

In Method $2$, you cannot apply limit to a part of the fraction. So

$$ = \frac{x^2(1 - \frac 1 x - \frac2 {x^2})}{x(1 + \frac1x)} - ax - b $$
is not equal to 
$$ = x - ax - b$$

In the above step you have applied limit to just a part of that fraction leaving behind $\dfrac{x^2}{x}$.

hope the answer is clear !

Comment: Have a look at the third property over here: http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcI/LimitsProperties.aspx

Comment: With the proof of that given over here: http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcI/LimitProofs.aspx#Extras_Limit_LimitProp