# Evaluate $ \lim_{x\rightarrow{\frac\pi2 }} (\sec(x) \tan(x))^{\cos(x)}$ without L'Hôpital's rule

Tags: calculus, limits, trigonometry

I have tried changing limit to $\lim_{x\rightarrow0}$ and use some trigonometry identity ($\sin^2(x)+\cos^2(x) = 1$ and $\sin (x+\pi/2) = \cos(x)$)  but doesn't work

I have no idea on how to do this now...

$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow{\frac\pi2 }} (\sec(x) \tan(x))^{\cos(x)} $$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First observe that if $u=\cos x$:

$$
\lim_{x\to \pi/2} (\sec x \tan x)^{\cos x}=\lim_{x\to \pi/2} \left(\frac{1}{\cos^2x}\right)^ {\cos x}=\lim_{u\to 0} \left(\frac{1}{u^2}\right)^ {u}
 $$
Now just assume that $L=\lim_{u\to 0} \left(\frac{1}{u}\right)^ {2u}$. You get:
$$
\ln L=\lim_{u\to 0} 2u\ln\left(\frac{1}{u}\right)=0 \implies L=1
$$

---

**Remark:** The last limit can be proved also without Hopital rule! To see this assume $y=\ln\left(\frac{1}{u}\right)$, then the limit turns out to be:
$$
\lim_{y\to\infty}2ye^{-y}
$$ 
To prove that the last limit is zero, we use the following inequality:

$$
0<2ye^{-y}\leq \frac{2y}{1+y+y^2/2}
$$
The limit of RHS goes to zero as $y\to\infty$.

Comment: He is taking $\lim_{x\to \pi/2} \sin x = 1$. I don't know how valid that might be though.

Comment: @ParthThakkar I didn't realized that, yes that is valid.

Comment: @experimentX: But I've come across some situations where this kind of 'partial' substitution doesn't work. Like this: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/367080/confusion-over-a-limit-different-ways-of-solving-give-different-answers

Comment: @experimentX, that isn't the best example to convey my point. What I basically am saying is that sometimes 'separating' the limits gives a different answer.

Comment: I'm not sure if taking the partial limit $\,\sin x\xrightarrow[x\to\pi/2]{}1\;$ is valid in this case but, at any rate, there should be a proof of this.

Comment: @ParthThakkar that is happening because your first term diverges as $x \to \text{ very high value }$  $x-2 \approx x $. in general if $\lim_{x \to n} f(x) g(x) = \lim_{x \to n} f(x) \cdot \lim_{x \to n} g(x)$ given that the limit exists and it is finite. BTW I don't see other answer is independent on L'Hopital

Comment: @DonAntonio, exactly my point. And experimentX, I agree that what you said holds true generally, however, I've come across certain limits where such a thing results only in absurdity. (Maybe I never understood the thing correctly!) For example:
$$ \lim_{x\to 0} \dfrac{\sin x - x} {x^3} \\ = \lim_{x\to 0} \left(\dfrac{\sin x} {x^3} - \dfrac 1 {x^2} \right) \\ = \lim_{x\to 0} \left(\dfrac{\sin x} {x}\dfrac 1 {x^2} - \dfrac 1 {x^2} \right) \\ = \lim_{x\to 0} \left(1\cdot \dfrac 1 {x^2} - \dfrac 1 {x^2} \right) = 0$$

Comment: @ParthThakkar the first term diverges, when it diveres, how asymptotically it behaves is important, not the constant, the following is (absurdly) true
$\lim_{x \to \infty} x = \lim_{x\to\infty} x + 1 $

Comment: @experimentX, ok. Fine, I agree with your answer for that question. But what would you say about the above (wrong) evaluation of the limit? I know this is not quite related to the question I gave a link to, but this is about the method used by Arash.

Comment: @ParthThakkar the method used by Arash is fine just take 
$\sin(x)^{\cos(x)}$ outside and take limit .. that gives 1. Only that I can't find a wake to make it independent of L'hopital.

Comment: @experimentX, I tried to leave open a little bit of excitement for proving the last part. But in any case, the proof of the last part is added too.

Comment: @ParthThakkar the limit exists it is $1$. Check it [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit+x-%3Epi%2F2+1%2F%28cos%5E2%28x%29%29%5Ecos%28x%29)

Comment: @experimentX, OK. I just checked on wolfram alpha. The limit $\lim_{x \to \pi/2} (\sec^2 x)^{\cos x} = 1$. So it is correct to separate the limits. I was under the impression that it didn't exist.

Comment: @ParthThakkar given that you can change $u = \pi/2 - x \to 0 $, this basically turns into (this type) $\sin(u)^{\sin(u)} \approx u^u , u\to 0$. it's easy to guess ... but to make it independent of L'hopital you have to show that $\lim_{x\to 0} x^x = 1$ without L'hopital.

Comment: How did $\frac{2y}{1+y+y^2/2}$ come?

Comment: @IndyZa Hint: Taylor expansion of $e^x$.

Comment: @Arash interesting!! i did't expect $x^x$ to be independent of L'hopital. (+1) extra.

Comment: $\large\abs{x\ln\left(x\right)}
\leq
\abs{x\left(x - 1\right)}
\to
0\quad\mbox{when}\quad x \to 0$.

Comment: @FelixMarin, That's much better!

Comment: @FelixMarin: This inequality is pretty wrong when $x > 0$ and $x$ is small. If this were true then by division with $|x|$ we would have $|\ln x| \leq |x - 1|$ and when $x \to 0^{+}$ the LHS tends to $\infty$ and RHS tends to $1$. So this is incorrect. I understand that this is perhaps due to "thinking in haste".

Comment: @FelixMarin: Proper proof of $x\log x \to 0$ as $x \to 0^{+}$ is done by taking $x = 1/t$ and then showing that $(\log t)/t \to 0$ as $t \to \infty$. This can be done by taking $\log t = 2 \log\sqrt{t} \leq2(\sqrt{t} - 1)$ for $ t > 1$ and then dividing by $t$ and by squeeze theorem we get the result.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: $$\lim_{t\to 0} \sin t \ln \frac{\cos t}{\sin^2t} = -2 \lim_{t\to 0} (\sin t \cdot \ln \sin t) = 0.$$

Comment: Don't understand why ln just appear in the equation..

Comment: He took $\ln$ of the limit. So, the $0$ he got is for $\ln(\text{limit})$ and not $\text{limit}$ as such.

Comment: Is it just $ln(y)=\lim_{t\to 0} \sin t \ln \frac{\cos t}{\sin^2t} = -2 \lim_{t\to 0} (\sin t \cdot \ln \sin t) = 0.$ ? So $ln(y) = 0 and y = e^0 = 1?$

Comment: Yeah. There was a correction in Arash's answer *just* now.

Answer (score 1):

$\lim_{x \to \pi/2}\left[\sec\left(x\right)\tan\left(x\right)\right]^{\cos\left(x\right)} = \lim_{x \to 0}x^{-2x} = \lim_{x \to 0}{\rm e}^{-2x\ln\left(x\right)}$.

Since
$\lim_{x \to 0}\left[-2x\ln\left(x\right)\right] = -2\lim_{x \to 0}{\ln\left(x\right) \over 1/x} = -2\lim_{x \to 0}{1/x \over -1/x^{2}} = 0$, $\displaystyle{\color{#ff0000}{\large\lim_{x \to \pi/2}\left[\sec\left(x\right)\tan\left(x\right)\right]^{\cos\left(x\right)} = 1}}$

$\newcommand{\abs}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\vert}$
${\bf\mbox{Without L'H$\hat{\rm o}$pital}}$:
$$
\abs{x\ln\left(x\right)}
\leq
\abs{x\left(x - 1\right)}
\to
0\quad\mbox{when}\quad x \to 0
$$

Comment: Without Hopital my friend :)

Comment: @Arash 0 k. I have to read carefully. Thanks.